# Expression for summation involving factorial

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

It is known that $ \sum_{k = 0}^{n} 
    {n \choose k} = 2^n$ and  $ \sum_{k = 0}^{n} 
    {n \choose k} (!k)= n!$. But is it known what 
$ \sum_{k = 0}^{n } {n  \choose k}(k!)$ is equal to?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n C_n^k k!=\int_0^\infty C_n^k x^k e^{-x}dx=\int_0^\infty (1+x)^n e^{-x}dx$ expressible via the incomplete Gamma function

Comment: Useful summary here: http://oeis.org/wiki/Subfactorial.

Answer (score 8):

See https://oeis.org/A000522 .   It is known (and not too hard to prove) that it is $\lfloor e \cdot n! \rfloor$ for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Jeffrey - Thank you so much for the answer. Btw, do you have a reference for the proof?

Comment: Note that the sum expands into $n!(\frac{1}{0!}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!})$; the sum in parentheses converges to $e$ from below, and can easily be shown to be in $(e-\frac{1}{n!},e)$.